# How to properly change the color of a mat-icon with angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have looked at the documentation and I have tried to change the color of a mat-icon like so:

```
<mat-icon class="white" color="primary" svgIcon="back"></mat-icon><span class="backText">back</span>
```

The above is how the element looks in the html. I have tried to change the color of the icon by adding a class with a color of white. Which does not work. I have tried adding the directive color="primary" which does not work either while all my buttons that look like this

```
 <button mat-button color='primary'>example button</button>
```

do receive the color. I want to get my mat-icon to change color with the color palette because this should work according to the docs. But ultimately I would also like to be able to change the color of the icon to white which is a color not on my color palette.

How can I change the color of `<mat-icon>` to a color from a working color palette as well as a color not on the color palette?

Thanks!

Comment: first of all check if your svg has "fill: currentColor" rule in all cases, it has to inherit color from parent

Comment: Using a CSS class to set the `color` value should work (but see Alexander2134's comment above), but you shouldn't use CSS color and the icon's color property together as in `class="white" color="primary"`.

Comment: @Alexandr2134 that was the issue. Thanks. Kinda wierd that this site https://material.io/icons/ would distribute the icons in a way that makes them unusable with color="primary"

Answer (score 40):

Use NgStyle directive.

```
<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':'white'}">home</mat-icon>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: i tried to use ngStyle="{ color: white }". Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Make sure to enclose ngStyle with brackets.

Answer (score 23):

You have two options to change the color of a `mat-icon`.

**Color Attribute**

You can use the `color` attribute which will use the value specified in your theme. It only accepts three attributes: `"primary"`, `"accent"` or `"warn"`.

```
<mat-icon color="primary" svgIcon="archive"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="accent" svgIcon="archive"></mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="warn" svgIcon="archive"></mat-icon>
```

**Custom Style**

Add a custom style class with `color` specified:

```
.green-icon {
    color: green;
}
```

Add class to your icon:

```
<mat-icon class="green-icon" svgIcon="archive"></mat-icon>
```

**Demo**

I have created a [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-efmlpm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) that changes color of an SVG `mat-icon`.

Comment: What about using mat-icon with multiple paths in the svg?

Comment: How you can change the arrow color as well. For instance from white to black?