# On routerLinkActive="active" change the color of child mat-icon inside button

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a header on my webpage with an item list and every item has a mat-icon child in it. Below is one of the items.

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/admin' ]" > 
   <button routerLink="['/admin']" routerLinkActive="active">
       <mat-icon color="warn">history</mat-icon>Audit
   </button>
</a>
```

The CSS on `routerLinkActive="active"` works fine on the button text, but I also want to change the color of mat-icon, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Try something like the following: [color]="condition ? 'primary' : 'warn'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to add this in your CSS -- probably best is to add it globally:

```
.active .mat-icon{
   color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please do select it as the best answer if you believe it was.

Answer (score 6):

The `RouterLinkActive` exports a variable to the template, and has a property that tells you what the active state currently is.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#properties

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ead169a4022e2a2f5520e1c1a58f30692b90f7cd/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L77

```html
   <button routerLink="['/admin']" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
      <mat-icon [color]="rla.isActive && 'warn'">history</mat-icon>Audit
  </button>
```

The above will set the color to `warn` if the property `isActive` of the `routerLinkActive` is *true*.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818921/how-to-properly-change-the-color-of-a-mat-icon-with-angular), you could do something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/admin' ]" > 
   <button routerLink="['/admin']" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
       <mat-icon [ngClass]="{'color': rla.isActive ? 'warn' : 'primary'}">history</mat-icon>Audit
   </button>
</a>
```

or this

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/admin' ]" > 
   <button routerLink="['/admin']" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
       <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': rla.isActive ? 'warn' : 'primary'}">history</mat-icon>Audit
   </button>
</a>
```

note that these answers are untested

Comment: Should the color change dynamically?

Comment: @al.koval assuming that `active` is a boolean, this should change dynamically

Comment: `active` is *not a template* variable. It is the string to assign to the `class` attribute of the button.

Comment: @Reactgular thanks for the clarity, I haven't used active router before. Using this [link](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
            <a routerLink="/Clients" routerLinkActive="active">
                <span class="menu_icon"><i class="material-icons">group</i></span>
                <span class="menu_title">Clients</span>
            </a>
        </li>

> add this sytle in global css


.active i {
        color: #28A745;
    }
    .active span {
        color: #28A745;
    }
```