# Change color - Pipe Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I wanted to perform 2 transformations in my Angular template.
The first is to change the direction of the arrow down if it is a negative number and if it is a positive number the arrow would change direction up. I did this using Pipe.

The second transformation is: if the number is negative, its color will be red, if it is positive, its color will be green.

This is the pipe I created for the arrows:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'topBar'
})
export class TopBarPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    if(value < 0){
     return 'arrow_downward'
    }
    else if(value > 0){
      return  'arrow_upward'
    }
    return ''
  }

}
```

This is the HTML calling the pipe:

```
 <mat-icon>{{
 qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | topBar
  }}</mat-icon>
```

The question of the arrows worked, but I don't know how to solve the question of changing the color if the number will be positive or negative.
How could I do?
Do I use the pipe too?

Comment: I would suggest using a directive and have the directive add a class to the `mat-icon`. That class could then change the `fill` using CSS... But I would have probably just wrapped `mat-icon` in another component that has an input for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a pipe just for changing the colour would be an overkill. You can achieve the same with the following:

```
<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{ color: (qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity < 0) ? 'red' : 'green' }">
  {{ qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | topBar }}
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define another pipe to get color based on value:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'iconColor'
})
export class IconColorPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    if (value < 0) {
      return 'red';
    }
    return 'green';
  }
}
```

then use `ngStyle` [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818921/how-to-properly-change-the-color-of-a-mat-icon-with-angular) to update color of `mat-icon`

```
<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{ 'color': qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | iconColor }">
  {{ qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | topBar }}
</mat-icon>
```